# tensorflow tf.py_func loading pickle Iterator throwing error, unknown shapes

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am writing a tf.data pipeline for input into `keras` later on. The thing is my data is in the form of pickle files. I have a list of file names passed to tf data, that I am going to load using a custom tf.py_func calling pickle within.

The problem arises when I try to build an iterator from the dataset, giving the error that

> "Cannot convert value , ),
>   types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)> to a TensorFlow DType."

I believe it is because tensorflow is unable to infer the shape of the loaded pickle data. I am a bit lost on how to proceed, or if this is possible in tf data at all.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset_filepath_list)

def parse_input_data_function(filename):
    # pickle file is a tuple, (data, label)
    histogram_data, label = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
    histogram_data = historgram_data.transpose(1, 0)
    histogram_data = historgram_data.reshape([-1, 8, 32])
    return histogram_data.astype('float32'), float(label)

dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda filename : tuple(tf.py_func(
        parse_input_data_function, [filename], [tf.float32, 
tf.float32])))

dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(dataset_filename_list))
    .batch(batch_size).repeat()

# this line is where the error occurs
training_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset, 
dataset.output_shapes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing the wrong arguments to`tf.data.Iterator.from_structure`. It should take (output_types, output_shapes), but you are giving a dataset and its shapes.
Try this:

```
training_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
```

And then, to use the iterator with the respective dataset:

```
input_data, output_data = training_iterator.get_next()
train_init = training_iterator.make_initializer(dataset)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, how could I have been so blind...I was reading the tf.py_func api docs and my mind keeps on thinking I did type .output_types and it is not working because tf was unable to infer the shape from the custom function.

Comment: it can happen ;)